# Ajaxsnapshot's proxy interfering with CloudFlare's proxy

Tags: snapshot, cloudflare, search-engine-bots

We are using CloudFlare service for CDN, Security and other services. And we are using Ajaxsnapshot for creating snapshots for Search Bots. The problem is we are getting Error 1000 - DNS points to incorrect IP. When we switch off CLoudFlare settings, Ajaxsnapshot API works and is able to create snapshots.
How to solve it so we can use both the services?

Answer (score 0):

You should contact CloudFlare support so we can look at your DNS zone file. It sounds like something isn't set properly in DNS, or you're pointing to an IP that it shouldn't be.